# If $A^n = I$, $n$ odd, $A$ a square integer matrix, does $A = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

**Edit:** Crap, even my hypothesis was wrong. If you put $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1&-1\\3&-2 \end{array} \right]$, then $A^3 = I$ but no eigenvalue is $1$. (What's true is that all eigenvalues are $n$th roots of unity.)

---

I ask this because I believe it might resolve a trickier problem I'm working on in a simple way. Obviously this is false if $n$ is even, but I have no counterexample if $n$ is odd. Indeed, if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$,

$$A^nx = \lambda^nx = Ix = x \implies \lambda = 1 $$

so $\lambda = 1$ is the only eigenvalue of the matrix. This says $\operatorname{trace}(A) = n$ and $p(\lambda) = (1 - \lambda)^n$. (Trivially, $\det(A) = 1$ from the multiplicativity of the determinant.)

(Incidentally, I am aware that there is a subtlety here in assuming a real eigenvector exists, since the rotation-by-$90^{\circ}$ matrix satisfies $A^4 = I$ and has none; but it seems that the condition that $A^n = I$ for *odd* $n$ may take care of this problem.)

How can we prove this, in a fairly simple way? (If the proof is complicated, I'm still game, but it's probably not the intended solution to my original problem.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not true. A simple counterexample for $n=3$ is
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
More complicated counterexamples for any $n$ can be constructed using permutation matrices.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the counterexample; it will make life more interesting.